# TCL array or List Manipulation to an variable

Tags: tcl

The following TCL function is called n number of times. Each time the numid and type is passed to this function, I am trying to lappend the numid for each type.

For example

If the values passed are as follows

```
2       BLACK
1       RED
1       BLACK
3       BLUE
1       BLUE
2       BLUE
2       RED
```

The output I am getting is following using set_numid_type function

```
black_color_str 2 1
red_color_str 1 2
blue_color_str 3 1 2
```

But the output I need is as follows. When type is not in sequence it should be appended to different variable type.

```
black_color_str 2 
red_color_str 1
black_color_str 1
blue_color_str 3 1 2 (since BLUE color is called in sequence)
red_color_str 2



proc set_numid_type {numid type} {

  variable black_color_str
  variable red_color_str
  variable blue_color_str

  if {$type == "BLACK"} {

      if {![info exists black_color_str] || ![llength $ black_color_str]} {
          set black_color_str ""
          }

       lappend black_color_str $numid
   }

   if {$type == "RED"} {

      if {![info exists red_color_str] || ![llength $ red_color_str]} {
          set red_color_str ""
         }

       lappend red_color_str $numid
   }

   if {$type == "BLUE"} {

      if {![info exists blue_color_str] || ![llength $ blue_color_str]} {
          set blue_color_str ""
          }

       lappend blue_color_str $numid
   }

}
```

Comment: Suggest posting the calling code as well. This is simply a matter of managing the state what the last colour was to determine if the current colour should be added to the sequence or create a new line.

Comment: The calling code is from xslt side which is as follows:

Comment: <xsl:template match="OPERATION[@type != 'SET_NUMTYP']" mode="setNumTypEnt">
    <xsl:variable name = "NumId" select="@NumId" />
    <xsl:variable name = "typeVar" select="@type" />
    <xsl:variable name="temp0" select="tcl:set_numid_type($NumId, $typeVar)" />
  </xsl:template>

Comment: @tcluser please explain how do you want the data to be used. Do you plan to use the variables in the calling procedure? to you need to print the output?

Comment: Hi Nir, I want the achieve the folllowing output which I will be passing to next function                                                               black_color_str 2 
red_color_str 1
black_color_str 1
blue_color_str 3 1 2 (since BLUE color is called in sequence)
red_color_str 2
                                                                     If the type is not passed in sequence, then it should be appended to different variable. I do not want to print out the output.

Comment: please let me know if anyone needs more clarification on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that operates on an input list and returns an output list.
You can modify it to work on global variables if you really want.

```
proc GroupSequences { inputPairs } {
    if {[llength $inputPairs] == 0} return {}       
    set sequences {}
    set lastColour ""
    set latestSequence {}
    foreach pair $inputPairs {
        puts 1
        if {"[lindex $pair 1]" != $lastColour} {
            puts 2
            if {[llength $latestSequence] > 0} {
                puts 3
                lappend sequences $latestSequence
            }
            puts 4
            set latestSequence [lreverse $pair]
            set lastColour [lindex $pair 1]
        } else {
            puts 5
            lappend latestSequence [lindex $pair 0]
        }
    }
    puts 6
    lappend sequences $latestSequence
    return $sequences
}

set input [list { 2 "black" } { 1 "red" } { 1 "black" } {3 "blue" } { 1 "blue" } { 2 "blue" } { 2 "red" } ]
set seq [GroupSequences $input]
```

Comment: Hi Ergwun,thanks for taking out time and answering my question, but I am specifically looking for the variable to be appended in the way I described in my required output. I just want each variables to be appended for numid only. I am trying to fix your code in editor, but if you could update your code with the requirements I am looking for, it will be great. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, no. The code you already posted shows how to append to variables outside the procedure. If there's a *specific* part you don't understand then ask another question about it.